# In words with a hyphen: Can I change LaTeX's default so it will break lines at different characters too?

Tags: hyphenation

By default LaTeX only does line-breaks after the dash in words that contain a dash. It will break 'multi-disciplinary' only at '-', but will not break at other characters ('mul-ti' or 'di-sci-pli-na-ry').

I know how to make it do so with exdash. But for my needs it would be better suited to change the **default** so LaTeX will use all possibilities to hyphen ('mul-ti-di-sci-pli-na-ry'). In other words: I would prefer to manually tell LaTeX when I don't want it to hyphen words containing a dash instead of manually telling it when to do so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You ca collect words wit nonstandard `\hyphenation{...}`, for example `\hyphenation{Za-r-ko}` (standard hyphenation is `Zar-ko`).

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to override this as a default. The closest you can come is to insert manual discretionary hyphens (using `\-`) where you'd like to allow a possible break.

Comment: As @DonaldHosek suggests, you can insert `\-` wherever else hyphenation ay be permitted,  Inserting `\hspace{0pt)` following the hyphen should allow the word *after* the hyphen to also be huphenated.